# Accessing array returned from str_split() throws me undefined offset error

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, split

I need to split the string `12345` into an array of characters. Using the following code I am getting:

> undefined offset error

Else I am having complete array echoed using `print_r()` function.

```
$arr = str_split('12345');
echo $arr[1];
```

**EDIT:**

Full code:

```
$id  = 4;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `time_table` WHERE user_info_iduser_info = $id OR tutor_detail_idtutor_detail = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);// 5 rows selected

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
     echo $row[3];  // outputs 12345
     $arr = str_split($row[3]);
     echo $arr[1]; // should output 2 but not working :(
}
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce your error](https://3v4l.org/5ZLU7) Please show us your **real** and **full** code

Comment: [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) - Convert a string to an array

Comment: works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/5qAiuH

Comment: complete code added @Rizier123

Comment: also working fine for me @newUser

Comment: well I figured out something.  I am having 12345 in a variable 
$row[3]
now when i use str_split($row[3]) it outputs r :(  why not reading value in variable

Comment: @newUser What is the **exact** output of: `highlight_string($row[3]);` ?

Comment: try casting to a string first - ie: (string)$row[3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code instead of `str_split`

```
$str="12345";
$str_len = strlen( $str );
$arr = array();
for ( $i = 0; $i < $str_len; $i++ )
{
    $arr[] = $str[$i];
    echo "<br>".$str[$i]."<br>";
}
print_r( $arr );
```